# ffmpeg file integrity check and rename on error with a batch file

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, batch-rename

I've found the code to check a file for errors and it creates a log file with the contents. Is there a way to alter it and rename a file that has errors but not the ones without?

```
@echo off

set "filtro=%1"
if [%filtro%]==[] (
    set "filtro=*.mp4"
    )

for /R %%a in (%filtro%) do call :doWork "%%a"

    PAUSE
    exit /B

:doWork
    "F:\- error check\ffmpeg.exe" -v error -i %1 -f null - > "%~1.log" 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Try using **`delayed expansion`** for your variables:

```bat
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

**2)** Verify if some extension (**`%~x1`**) was provided in argument:

```bat
if /i "%~x1"=="" (set "_filtro=.mp4") else set "_filtro=%~x1"
```

**3)** Use **`For /F`** and **`Where.exe /R`** loop command, where you can recursively **list/process** your files:

```bat
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r . "*!_filtro!"'
```

**4)** Take advantage of the operator **`||`**, for to rename any file that has an error:

```bat
"!_ffmpeg!" -i "%%~i" -v error -f null - || ren "%%~i" "%%~ni_ERROR_%%~xi"
```

**5)** Use **`Clip`** command for copy your log file content to your **ClipBoard**/**<kbd>Crtl+C</kbd>**:

```bat
type .\error.log|"%__APPDIR__%clip.exe"
```

**6)** If you prefer, you can also replace **`Pause`** to **`Timeout.exe`**, and/or, **`exit /b`** to **`goto :EOF`**:

```bat
"%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /t -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

echo\ & cd/d "%~dp0" && >nul cd.>.\error.log

set "_ffmpeg=F:\- error check\ffmpeg.exe"
if /i "%~x1"=="" (set "_filtro=.mp4") else set "_filtro=%~x1"

echo\Filtro: ..\*!_filtro! && for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r . "*!_filtro!"'
)do echo\%%~i && 2>>error.log ("!_ffmpeg!" -i "%%~i" -v error -f null - || ren "%%~i" "%%~ni_ERROR_%%~xi")

type error.log | "%__APPDIR__%clip.exe" & "%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /t -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

- Same code in compacted formatting:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && echo\ & cd/d "%~dp0" & >nul cd.>.\error.log

set "_ffmpeg=F:\- error check\ffmpeg.exe" && if /i "%~x1"=="" (set "_filtro=.mp4") else set "_filtro=%~x1"
echo\Filtro: ..\*!_filtro! && for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r . "*!_filtro!"'
)do echo\%%~i && 2>>error.log ("!_ffmpeg!" -i "%%~i" -v error -f null - || ren "%%~i" "%%~ni_ERROR_%%~xi")
echo/ && type .\error.log|"%__APPDIR__%clip.exe" & "%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe" /t -1 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

---

**For command line help, you can use `/?`:**

```bat
Ren /?, For /?,Where /?, Endlocal /?, Goto /?, Timeout /?, SetLocal /?, if /?
```

**On the internet, you can get more help on:**

- **[Ren](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)**
- **[For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**
- **[Endlocal](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)**
- **[Goto :EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)**
- **[Timeout.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)**
- **[EnableDelayedExpansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028)**
- **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
- **[If, Else If, Else, If Defined, Errorlevel ...](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

Comment: Hey, this is way over my head, but i'll try it out. Thank you very much for taking the time.